# An Issue with Three20

Tags: ios, three20

I'm trying to use Three20 in my project. I'm getting some errors, lots of warnings. I understand most of them. But I cannot understand one type of errors. I see in many places imports like this:

## import "Three20Network/private/TTRequestLoader.h"

Note "private" there. Compiler says file not found. And maybe I'm missing something being new to iOS, but there is no "private" directory inside Three20Network. TTRequestLoader.h is right there inside Three20Network together with the rest of the files. And there are lots of imports like that. So what is the deal with this "private" thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing the search headers setting from your target.
Please see this alternative automatic way of setting up three20:
http://three20.info/article/2010-10-06-Adding-Three20-To-Your-Project

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what's wrong, however, try:

- Make sure to use the latest development branch
  (https://github.com/facebook/three20/tree/development)
- If it's a new project, try using the `ttmodule.py` install script.
  it's the easiest way to install three20 these days: http://three20.info/article/2011-03-10-Xcode4-Support